# Should the HResult property be used to discern different types of FormatException?

Tags: c#

In one place, in need to catch a `FormatException` of a certain kind. Namely, the one that says "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.".
Doing:

```
catch (FormatException x)
{
    if (x.Message == "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.")
    {
        // do something special...
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

seems like a bad idea because the `Message` property might be localized. So instead, I was thinking of using the `HResult` like this:

```
catch (FormatException x)
{
    if (x.HResult == -2146233033)
    {
        // do something special...
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Is this a valid approach? I.e. will different kinds of `FormatException`s get different `HResult` values? Or is there a better approach to this? Also, if this is a valid approach, is the magic constant -2146233033 defined somewhere to be reused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implies that *any* `FormatException` will have that HRESULT:

> `FormatException` uses the HRESULT `COR_E_FORMAT`, which has the value 0x80131537.

(`0x80131537` is the 32-bit hex representation of -2146233033).

So I doubt you can use that property to distinguish different types of `FormatException`s.  Is there no checking you can do before the exception is thrown?

Comment: Yes I can but it involves parsing the format string to count the number of arguments. Thanks for the hint!